# ListBox causes program to crash when clicking in an empty area

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, listbox

I'm creating a flip card program that lets you insert a word and it's description. The word is added to a ListBox whilst the description is held in a string array. I've told the program to find the correct description once a ListBox item is clicked as shown in the code below. although this causes the program to crash if the user clicks on an empty area in the ListBox. How can I get around this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] details = new string[20];

    private void insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(inserttbx.Text); //Adds word to the ListBox
    }

    private void editDescbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        details[i] = descriptiontbx.Text; //adds text from descriptiontbx to "details" array
        i++;
    }

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(i == 0) //int i equals the amount of items in the ListBox.
        {

        }
        else
        {
            int b = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            descriptiontbx.Text = details[b]; 
            //"details" string array, will open the correct description
            //depending on which ListBox item is selected.
        }
    }
}
```

[Diagram of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnWL5.png)

Translations:

Infoga: Insert
Redigera: Edit

Note that all the functions in the program are not included in the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox.SelectedIndex` is:

> A zero-based index of the currently selected item. A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Therefore if no item is selected:

```
        int b = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        descriptiontbx.Text = details[b];
```

will cause the crash as b is -1, which is out of range for an array. Add a check to make sure that `SelectedIndex >= 0` before trying to use the value.